# WordPress: Difference between rewind_posts(), wp_reset_postdata() and wp_reset_query()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

What is difference between WordPress functions `rewind_posts()`, `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` and when I should use them?

If I have this part of code in `single.php`:

```
$query = new WP_Query($some_args);
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    ...
endwhile;
```

is this equal to this:

```
$query = new WP_Query($some_args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ...
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two statements in your question aren't equal.

In the first block you're looping through posts returned by your custom WP_Query, `$query`.

In the second block `$query` doesn't do anything and the posts are actually from the global `$wp_query`.

Let's look at what each of the three functions you mentioned do.

`rewind_posts()` - This does exactly what it sounds like. After you've run a loop this function is used to return to the beginning allowing you to run the same loop again.

`wp_reset_postdata()` - In your first block of code you run a custom WP_Query. This will modify the global `$post` variable. After that query has been run using `wp_reset_postdata()` will restore the global `$post` variable back to the first post in the main query.

`wp_reset_query()` - This should be used if you change the global `$wp_query` or use `query_posts()` (I wouldn't suggest using `query_posts()`). It resets `$wp_query` back to the original.

Further reading:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: You should avoid using `query_posts` though. Still +1 for a great answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen I agree Pieter :) I suggested that in my answer but it may be worth emphasising a little more. Still a lot of people do use the function so it's worth knowing how `wp_reset_query()` fits in with it. Thanks for the +1

Comment: Related: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753)

Comment: "In your first block of code you run a custom WP_Query. This will modify the global $post variable." - actually, the problem not in the WP_Query itself, the problem in the calling the_post() function. the_post() function will modify the global $post variable, but not WP_Query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rewind post - Rewinds to the beginning of the cycle.It generally the clears the current loop. Example

```
<? Php  
/ / use the cycle for the first time 
if ( have_posts ( )  ) {  while ( have_posts ( ) ) { the_post ( ) ;  ?> 
    < ! - - display information about the post - - > 
<? php  }  }  ?>


    < ! - - any - anything any code - - >


<? Php  
/ / use the cycle for the second time 
/ / rewind to the beginning of the cycle to once again ispolzvoat heve_posts () 
rewind_posts ( ) ; 
if ( have_posts ( )  ) {  while ( have_posts ( ) ) { the_post ( ) ;  ?> 
    < ! - - display information about the post - - > 
<? php  }  }  ?>
```

You probably don’t need wp_reset_query(). wp_reset_query() unsets the main $wp_query variable, then resets it to the value of $wp_the_query, and then runs wp_reset_postdata(). Well, if you’re not using query_posts(), then you really shouldn’t be messing with the main $wp_query variable, as wp_reset_query() does.

All you need to do after a custom WP_Query is use wp_reset_postdata(), which resets various global post variables to their original values.

Reference [here](http://www.poststat.us/properly-reset-wordpress-query/)